# Are there different characters that appear exactly the same in browsers' url lines?

Tags: web-browser

I've heard of phishing scams using misspellings of urls. But can a url look ***exactly*** the same as a legit one in the address bar, while actually being a different url?

Comment: You are probably looking for [IDN homopgrahic attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDN_homograph_attack) like in [this example](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/04/18/homograph_attack_again/).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes. You can convert your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But can a url look ***exactly*** the same as a legit one in the address bar, while actually being a different url?

Yes, that can occur. It's an advanced phishing technique known as [IDN homograph attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDN_homograph_attack).

Homographs (or homoglyphs) are characters that look very similar or even identical. When browsers started supporting internationalized domain names, it became possible to display non-latin characters in URLs, so you could theoretically mix different languages in one domain name.

Can you tell the difference between these?

```
http://exаmple.com/
http://example.com/
```

(The first `a` is actually cyrillic.)

As a response to homograph attacks, browser vendors have established their own IDN policies (e.g. [Google Chrome](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/idn-in-google-chrome), [Mozilla Firefox](https://wiki.mozilla.org/IDN_Display_Algorithm)). They mitigate the problem mostly by blacklisting potentially confusable characters and displaying URLs with non-latin symbols as [Punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) under certain conditions. That's why your browser will display the first URL as `http://www.xn--exmple-4nf.com/` when you visit it.

Converting potentially misleading URLs while maintaining usability (e.g. you would still want to display a literal `ä` to someone in Germany) has turned out to be somewhat elusive which is why even in 2017 there are still [new homograph attacks](https://www.xudongz.com/blog/2017/idn-phishing/) being reported.